# DocuSign API language support

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to get DocuSign to send out emails for signing documents in French. We are aware of one way which is by changing the receiver's User Preferences. 
What I would like to know is, is it possible to send out emails in French by using the DocuSign APIs.i.e. by adding a setting in the DocuSign Envelpoe? 
Any information regarding this will be extremely helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: If you are using the REST API, please see the documentation here: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=language , specifically around these 3 parameters: emailBody, emailSubject,
supportedLanguage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to alter language settings for your signers:

1. The `supportedLanguage` field on the `emailNotification` property that you set in your JSON or XML request body.
2. The Resource Files found in Branding section of your account preferences.
3. The client's browser language setting (controls language in the DocuSign Console).

For the `supportedLanguage` property your JSON would look something like:

```
"emailNotification": {
    "emailSubject": "Custom email subject",
    "emailBody": "Custom email body",
    "supportedLanguage": "en"
  },
```

[This page](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=language) of the documentation lists the possible enumeration values for the various languages that are supported by DocuSign.

For #2, see [this page](https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-admin-guide/account-admin/branding) for info on Branding and Resource Files.

**Note**:  You might have to enable "Allow sender to set email language for recipients" option through your Preferences -> Features page in the Classic DocuSign Console.  If you don't see that option contact your account manager or support to have it enabled.

[image]